# Sort By date in hasMany relation first record for Laravel project

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, orm

I have a `courses` table and every course has many  `sessions`,

So I need to sort courses by the first session of the course date for Laravel Project.

Comment: https://reinink.ca/articles/ordering-database-queries-by-relationship-columns-in-laravel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this way you can set a method in Course model to get the oldest Session model(which means first session):

```
public function oldestSession()
{
   return $this->hasOne(Session::class)->oldestOfMany();
}
```

and then you may simply query your course model by adding constraints on that method :

```
$courses = Course::with(['oldestSession' => function ($query) {
    $query->orderBy('created_at', 'desc');
}])->get();
```